# Python: Are instance methods first-class objects?

Tags: python

In python, is there a way of doing the following?

```
for method in list_of_methods:
   class_instance.method(data)
```

I would think this to be possible in python, since many things are 1st class objects.

Edit:
Using some comments below, I tried this:

```
class Class_Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def method1(self, data):
        print(f"Method 1: {data}")
    def method2(self,data):
        print(f"Method 1: {data}")
        
list_of_methods = ["method1","method2"]
for method in list_of_methods:
    getattr(Class_Test(),method)("inside for loop")
```

Comment: That would be `getattr(class_instance, method_name)(data)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a function of a module by using its name (a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `list_of_methods` is a list of strings of method names, use `getattr` to get the bound instance method by name, then call it.

```
for method in list_of_methods:
    getattr(class_instance, method)(data)
```

If, instead, `list_of_methods` is a list of unbound methods from the same class,

```
for method in list_of_methods:
    method(class_instance, data)
```

I.e.,

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def make_sound(self, volume):
        print(f"{self.name} makes a sound at volume {volume}")


list_of_animals = [Animal("Puppo"), Animal("Catto")]
list_of_method_names = ["make_sound"]
list_of_methods = [Animal.make_sound]

for animal in list_of_animals:
    for method_name in list_of_method_names:
        getattr(animal, method_name)(15)
    for method in list_of_methods:
        method(animal, 24)
```

prints out

```
Puppo makes a sound at volume 15
Puppo makes a sound at volume 24
Catto makes a sound at volume 15
Catto makes a sound at volume 24
```

Comment: I really enjoyed the unbounded methods list way of doing it. ;)